# How do I change the simple form below run to Ajax with PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform, ajax-forms

I need to change the form whose markup and php code is as seen below to operate without loading the page. So it will be an Ajax PHP form. I'm pretty new to ajax. Someone please guide me on how to go about        it. I'll be very grateful.

Please note that a copy of the form data filled out by the visitor should be emailed to the visitor.

MARKUP IS AS BELOW:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Contact form to email</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="myemailform">
<form action="contact.php" method="post" name="myemailform">
Enter Name: <input name="name" type="text" /> 
Enter Email Address: <input name="email" type="text" /> 
Enter Message:<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send Form" />&nbsp;
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="myform.js"></script> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>





<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contact form to email</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" name="myemailform" action="contact.php">

Enter Name: <input type="text" name="name">

Enter Email Address:    <input type="text" name="email">

Enter Message:  <textarea name="message"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Send Form">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP CODE IS (contact.php):

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_from = 'me@mysite.com';

$email_subject = "New Form submission";

$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
                        "Here is the message: $message.\n";  

$aEmails = array();
$aEmails[] = 'me@mysite.com';
$aEmails[] = $visitor_email;


$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

foreach($aEmails as $aEmail) {
mail($aEmail,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
}


?>
```

THE JS CODE:

```
$('form#myemailform').on('submit',function(e){
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'contact.php',
    data: $('form#myemailform').serialize(),
    success: function (res) {
alert(res);
}
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `id` in your form and pass it through `ajax` something like this:

```
$('form#myemailform').on('submit',function(e){
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/your/php/page/path',
        data: $('form#myemailform').serialize(),
        success: function (res) {
            alert(res);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

In your `PHP` page you can access all your `POST` variables. And you are ready to go...

PS: There must be `JQuery` library imported before running this script.

Comment: Thanks Ronak. But my page is still loading. Please check how have done it above.

Comment: change this: `<form action="contact.php" method="post" name="myemailform" id="myemailform">`

Answer (score 0):

An example for you

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('form[name=myemailform]').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                //console.log(data); //data is which is echoing in PHP end. 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var postdata = $(this).serializeArray(),
    $.post(url, postdata, function(results){
        //success code
    }); 
});
</script>
```